# Using environment variables with @ConfigMapping

Tags: config, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 2.16 with an application.properties file. The problem I have is with @ConfigMapping and map. Looking at the docs here at 1.5.3: https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/config-mappings#nested-groups

It describes how to use a map inside your application.properties. I can't figure out how to change this map with environment variables. Is this possible?

Often I want to set my properties using environment variables like this:

`application.folder=${FOLDER:folder}`

Here I can use the FOLDER environment variable to change the application properties.

If possible this would allow me to deploy my application with just config changes, without needing to change the application.properties file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but remember that environment variables cannot represent the full spectrum of regular property names. For all the conversion rules, please check: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#environment-variables

You don't need to add an extra layer of indirection with expressions in your example. Because environment variables have a higher ordinal than `application.properties`, you can set any value and override it with `APPLICATION_FOLDER`.

Quarkus also supports external properties files, either in a working directory `config` or adding arbitrary files with the configuration `quarkus.config.locations. Please check:

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#application-properties-file

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#quarkus-config-config_quarkus.config.locations

Comment: Thanks. It looks like quarkus.config.locations also does what I was looking for.